# My carousel is changing heights when image is changed

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap carousel and set its height and width and also of images but still when the image changes the height of the carousel changes
Is there any way that even if the height width changed the side of carousel remains the same?

```
<div id="imageDiv">
                <div id="productImages" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#productImages" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#productImages" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#productImages" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#productImages" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                  </ol>


                  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                      <img width="200" height="200" src="<?php echo image_check($product['product_image1']); ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['product_name']; ?>">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                      <img width="200" height="200" src="<?php echo image_check($product['product_image2']); ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['product_name']; ?>">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                      <img width="200" height="200" src="<?php echo image_check($product['product_image3']); ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['product_name']; ?>">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                     <img width="200" height="200" src="<?php echo image_check($product['product_image4']); ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['product_name']; ?>">
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#productImages" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#productImages" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                  </a>
                </div>




              </div>

<style>
 .productImages .carousel-indicators .carousel-inner
                {
                  width: 200px;
                  height: 400px;
                }
</style>
```

Comment: Add your CSS classes, helping you is difficult without them. Thanks

Comment: I have given a bit of css that I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do with this?

```
.productImages .carousel-indicators .carousel-inner
    {
        width: 200px;
        height: 400px;
    }
```

Because what that's targeting is `.carousel-inner` inside of `.carousel-indicators` that are inside of `.productImages`. I think you're going for the opposite. If you're trying to target all of them try seperating the ID/classes with commas. Also `.productImages` should be `#productImages` because it's an ID.

Answer (score 0):

Your `productImages` is an `id`, not a `class` you're targeting in css.

And `carousel-inner` is not inside of `carousel-indicators`.

```
#productImages .carousel-inner
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
}
```